# Is Naples (Florida) still affected by Irma aftermath?

Tags: usa, event-based-effects, florida

I am attempting to determine if the city of Naples Florida will be back to normal for thanksgiving this year.

I have tried multiple google attempts, but have had not luck finding a resource that measures how impacted, or how far recovered a city is after a hurricane.

Does anyone know of a decent resource for this information?  Anyone on the site actually live in the area and can say?  Basically I want to know that most things are operational and that most of the beaches and such are clear. I know it way to early for all of it to be open, but what % of the damage has been fixed?

Is Fort Meyers less damaged?

Things we are interested in

1. Thanksgiving dinner ( Kroger or publix open )
2. Local entertainment \ night life
3. Restaurants
4. Beach
5. Some tourist stuff for the kids ( youngest is 10 )

Comment: Welcome to TSE. The question as framed is very difficult to answer; what do you consider "normal"? Depending on what restaurants and other businesses and attractions you patronize, it might be "normal" already, or it might be "try again in a year."

Comment: @choster help me out here, as a travel newbie.  Basically I want to know that most things are operational and that most of the beaches and such are clear.  I know it way to early for all of it to be open, but what % of the damage has been fixed?  Does that help?

Comment: If you [edit] the post to indicate a few of the things you intend to do in Naples over Thanksgiving, we could better answer. The local paper has a [hurricane updates](http://www.naplesnews.com/weather/hurricanes/) page which notes as of Oct. 12 that *While debris can still be seen throughout the island a majority of the buildings, businesses, and homes remain structurally sound as tourists continue to flock to the area*.

Comment: @choster Question updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  The area is near fully operational.  I was there last week.

You will see random damage here and there and people are still piling debris but none of that should affect you.  Unless a business was substantially damaged, it is open.  All of the waterfront restaurants in Ft. Myers were open.

I recall only one gas station still closed because their canopy blew over.

You'll have to check the website of any attraction specifically.  Note, the **outer half of the Pier is still closed** and will be for quite some time.

Southwest Florida is not a wasteland.  If you didn't know a Hurricane had passed, you probably couldn't tell a Hurricane had passed.